# What is the meaning of bounded in this sentence: The dogs bounded past their leader

Tags: meaning

I came across this sentence:

> The dogs bounded past their leader.

What does "bounded past" mean? I know the past tense of bind is bound. But here the verb "bounded" is used. Is the root of "bounded" different from the verb "bind"?

Comment: Have you checked the dictionary definition of the _verb_ [bound](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bounded)?

Comment: bound, bounded, bounded versus bind, bound, bound. Tricky, eh?

Comment: It means roughly the same as "galloped".

Comment: Thank you all for the response

Answer (score 1):

Here, 'bound' means to run with leaping strides. This sense comes from the French root similarly seen in 'rebound'. [Source: etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bound#:%7E:text=bound%20(v.2))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The French verb "bondir" means to leap or to jump.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, 'bounded' simply means 'ran'. It has nothing to do with being tied up.